# How can I pass a variable from function x to function y and a varible from function y to functio x without run the whole function

Tags: javascript

How can I pass a variable from function x to function y and a varible from function y to function x without run the whole function. For Example below I want to sent the z variable from function two to function one and the y variable from function one to function two but without run the function two, just send the variable value.

```
  function one(x) {
  var y;
  y = x+1;
}


function two(z) {
  z = 9;
  var k = y +9;
  one(z)
}
```

Is a way to do that? Or it is not achievable with this way?

Comment: this is extremely fuzzy, nonsense and incomprehensible. Why would you want to "send" a variable to a function if you don't need to call the function? if you don't need the function, then just leave it the frick alone.

Comment: I just need the value of the variable.

Comment: you wouldn't send that value, you would make the variable global!

Comment: Why not simply `return` that value?

Comment: but I cant set as global this:                                      var freq1 = document.getElementById("frequency").value;

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have:

```
function one(x) {
  var y;
  y = x+1;
}


function two(z) {
  z = 9;
  var k = y +9;
  one(z)
}
```

From what I can understand you need to do this:

```
var z = 9;

function one(x) {
  var y;
  y = x+1;
}


function two() {
  z = 9;
  var k = y +9;
  one()
}
```

However, it is extremely difficult to understand what you want to achieve. Can you give a scenario as to where you will use this kind of code?